# Tomcat with APR still says aprConnector is false

Tags: java, tomcat, https, apr

This is the connector in server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150"
               SSLEnabled="true"
               scheme="https"
               compression="off"
               connectionTimeout="1190"
               address="0.0.0.0"
               >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="/etc/ssl/certs/private.key"
                         certificateFile="/etc/ssl/certs/public.pem"
                          />
        </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

The goal with this connector is speed with HTTP2 and APR, along with HTTPS.

We installed tomcat native using the OS package tomcat-native.

Log output on startup:

> INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded
>   APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.16] using APR version
>   [1.6.3].
>
> INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR
>   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
>   random [true].
>
> INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent
>   APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]

Everything looks great, except for the **useAprConnector [false]**

So is APR actually doing anything?

I can't find anything in the relevant documentation:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/apr.html

Comment: Note that you are configuring Tomcat 8.5 but are reading the 8.0 documentation...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current default in Tomcat 8.5 is to use the Java NIO connector with OpenSSL as the crypto engine. `libtcnative` is still required, which requires `libapr`, but the "APR Connector" itself is not being used.

That means that Tomcat is using a pure-Java connector with the OpenSSL engine for crypto. You get the benefits of OpenSSL's speed without some of the downsides of the APR connector itself.

IMO this is the best configuration option available to you, so you should leave it unless you have a compelling reason to use the APR connector explicitly.

If you really want to use the APR connector, then you will need to set the [`useAprConnector` attribute on your `AprLifecycleListener` to `true`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/listeners.html#APR_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener).

Comment: Docs should contain everything, but I have a long history with Tomcat. If there is something specific you can't find, please post a complaint to the users mailing list and someone will try to correct it.

Comment: In high traffic production environments shouldn't we use useAprConnector=true ?

Comment: @dv3 The NIO and NIO2 connectors are non-blocking for one additional scenario on top of APR. Non-blocking I/O will scale better in all environments, and provide better service in a high-traffic production environment. There is some discussion of dropping the APR connector in future versions because the performance benefit of APR was primarily due to the OpenSSL engine for TLS. Now that is available through the NIO connectors, so the APR connector no longer has a perceivable benefit.